# How to set slow query log in MariaDB my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.6, my.cnf, performance, slow-log

It should be easy, but when I put these lines:

```
log_slow_queries = 1
long_query_time = 1
log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes
```

in `[mysqld]`, MariaDB fails to restart.

I looked at the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/slow-query-log-overview/#activating-the-slow-query-log), but could not figure out what is wrong in my configs.

Also , I've set the file permission to `/var/log/mysql/slow_query.log`

```
# ls -al /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mysql mysql 744682 Dec  4 23:46 /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log
```

However, I can set the parameters in command line:

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file = '/var/log/mysql/slow_query.log';
SET GLOBAL LONG_QUERY_TIME = 1;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
```

and see that they are set:

```
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                                                                                                        |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| log_slow_filter     | admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,full_join,full_scan,query_cache,query_cache_miss,tmp_table,tmp_table_on_disk |
| log_slow_rate_limit | 1                                                                                                            |
| log_slow_verbosity  |                                                                                                              |
| slow_launch_time    | 2                                                                                                            |
| slow_query_log      | ON                                                                                                           |
| slow_query_log_file | /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log                                                                                |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and even the slow queries are being written to the log. But I want to make the config persistent by writing them to my.cnf. So appreciate your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You said you added this

```
log_slow_queries = 1
long_query_time = 1
log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes
```

[That's the old way MySQL 5.0 sets the slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries).

To activate the slow query log for MySQL 5.6 and MariaDB, you must use the following

- [slow_query_log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#slow_query_log)
- [slow_query_log_file](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#slow_query_log_file)

Therefore, you need this in `my.cnf`

```
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow_query.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes
```